# jQuery statements inside $.post() not working properly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, post

I have the following code from my jQuery script that makes some changes to a div `fnbtn`, when the Esc key is pressed:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode==27) {
    if(window.discon==0)
    {
    window.discon = 1;
    $("#fnbtn").replaceWith("<div id=\"fnbtn\"><p id=\"fnbtnp\">The variable is one...<br>Blah blah...<\/p><\/div>");
        }
    else if(window.discon==1)
    { 
    window.discon=2;
    $.post(
      'do.php',
      {doit: 4, uid: window.uid},
      function(rcvd) { 
        $("#fnbtn").replaceWith("<div id=\"fnbtn\"><p id=\"fnbtnp\">The variable is two...<br>Blah blah...<\/p><\/div>");
        $("#disp").append("<p><span id=\"cmnt2\">"+rcvd+"</span></p>");
        });
    //alert("Alert something here");
    }
  }
 });
```

`disp` is another div to which the data received from the `$.post` request is appended. The `do.php` file contains some mysql queries and the following statement :

```
echo "This is the data returned from the do.php file";
```

Here's my problem. When I put this script in my php file, the div `fnbtn` changes successfully on pressing `Esc` the first time. But when `Esc` is pressed a second time, the div `fnbtn` fails to change. I think this has something to do with the `$.post()` request.

But when I include the `alert()` statement (which is currently commented out), everything works out just fine, and I can see the changes made, before I press the `OK` button on the alert box.

What is the cause of this problem? Is it caused because the `$.post()` request completes before the `$("#fnbtn").replaceWith()` and `$("#disp").append()` statements are executed? and how does including the `alert()` make a difference?

Your help is appreciated. Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: I can't see how adding that alert() would change how this works or doesn't work. I'm interested to see what others say.

Comment: If the alert is making a difference, that's a pretty good indication that this is either a race condition, or synchronous code in an asynchronous environment. Are you sure your page isn't refreshing?

Comment: I'm sure my page is not refreshing. But it constantly (every second) queries a table and appends a line or two of text to `#disp` if a particular condition is met. Do u think stopping this querying when `Esc` is pressed a second time, and _then_ trying out the above will work? But I'm thinking that since its jQuery, its not actually refreshing the whole page, nor the `#disp`, but just appends to it. Does that make a difference? @KevinB

Answer (score 0):

*If you set `window.discon = 2` doesn't that mean that `if(window.discon == 0)` and `if(window.discon == 1)` will return false and won't run a second time?
I have tried your code and for me it works fine up to the part mentioned above. Adding the `alert()` doesn't seem to make any difference, although it does run before `$.post()` is completed.*

Disregard what I said there, it seems I didn't quite understood what exactly you were referring too.

After playing with the code a little I didn't find anything wrong with it so it may be because of a different script that you have. 
For me it works with and without the `alert()`

You can try and play a little with the code and also add a `.fail` function

```
 $.post('do.php', {doit: 4, uid: window.uid}, function(rcvd) {
           $rcvd = rcvd;
        }).done(function(){
           $("#fnbtn").replaceWith("<div id=\"fnbtn\"><p id=\"fnbtnp\">The variable is two...<br>Blah blah...<\/p><\/div>");
           $("#disp").append("<p><span id=\"cmnt2\">" + $rcvd + "</span></p>");            
        }).fail(function(){
            alert('Could not reach do.php');        
       });
```

The only difference with the `alert()` is that the page is being stopped from being executed any further until the user clicks ok. That makes me think that there may be some other script that is colliding with this one.

Comment: Up to which part? And the `if(window.discon == 0)` is supposed to return `false` the second time. And I don't think `if(window.discon == 1)` will return `false` the second time - `window.discon = 1` when the `Esc` key is pressed the second time. I think I mentioned that the code works great when I add the `alert()`, which as you can see, is inside the `else if(window.discon ==1)` block. Any help is appreciated.